# ETL package configuration problem: how to set GeneratedFromPackageID?

Tags: ssis, configuration, etl

I have created an ETL package and done the most parts. I just need to set the configurations so this package can not only work on my computer but also work on other servers. I want to configure the Property Path. Here it comes to my problem: what is the "GeneratedFromPackageID"? How can I set it? Is it static or dynamic? Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeneratedFromPackageID is a GUID (unique ID) that in this case is specifying the GUID of the package that generated the configuration. If you look at the SSIS package in Code mode, you should see an XML attribute named DTSID. This is the Package ID. It is static unless you re-create the package or change the GUID manually.

Comment: Thx! I get what you say!